# If $f:G \rightarrow G$ is a group homomorphism and $f(ab) = f(b)f(a)$ does this show that $f$ is NOT a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

> Suppose $G$ is a group and $f : G \to G$ is the function $f(x) = x^{-1}$.
>
> Prove that if $f$ is a homomorphism, then $G$ is abelian.

Proceeding by contrapositive suppose $G$ is not abelian then for every $a,b$ in $G$,
$$f(ab) = {(ab)^-}^1 = {b^-}^1{a^-}^1 = f(b)f(a);$$

thus $f$ is not a homomorphism since the homomorphism property $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ fails.

My question is different from the possible duplicate provided because I want to know if showing that $$f(ab) = {(ab)^-}^1 = {b^-}^1{a^-}^1 = f(b)f(a);$$ is a correct method to show that a function is NOT a homomorphism

Comment: Technically, we don't know if $f(a)f(b) \neq f(b) f(a)$ provided only that $G'$ is not abelian.

Comment: What is your question? Whether $f(x) = x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism for non-abelian $G$? What does the title have to do with that?

Comment: Your two lines of solution can be combined to get a clear and direct proof. (Noting also that $f$ is surjective.)

Comment: @Paul Frost I wanted to provide an example of my more general question

Comment: I know that there is a direct proof of this question, but my question is can we show the homomorphism property fails by showing that $f(ab) = f(b)f(a)$                   (that is it should of been $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$)

Comment: Your title states $f:G\to G'$, but your statement says $f:G\to G$.

Comment: $f(ab) = f(b)f(a)$ does not necessarily imply that $f$ is not a homomorphism. It may be the case that $f(b)f(a) = f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b$ even if $G$ is not abelian. For a simple example, the trivial homomorphism $f(g) = 1$ always satisfies this condition. More generally, $f$ satisfying $f(ab) = f(b)f(a)$ will be a homomorphism if and only if the image of $f$ (which may be a proper subgroup of $G$) is abelian.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. So my contrapositive proof for this case is correct?

Comment: No. Again, if you don't know a thing about this $f$ as well as its $\mathrm {Im}f$, you cannot assert that $f(ab) = f(b) f(a)$ does not fit in the definition of homomorphism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

It is enough to show that $f(ab)=f(b)f(a)$ for some homomorphism $f$. This holds when the domain group is abelian.

---

We have for a homomorphism $f:G\to G, x\mapsto x^{-1}$ that

$$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)\tag{1}.$$

From the LHS of $(1)$, we have $f(ab)=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=f(b)f(a)$.

From the RHS of $(1)$, we have $f(a)f(b)=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Hence $b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Hence $G$ is abelian.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to know If you can prove the contrapositive of the statement and more generally I am wondering if the homomorphism property fails if $f(ab) = f(b)f(a)$ (that is it should of been $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$)

Comment: I've edited my answer now, @bluesky11. Is that better?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the title question. If $a,b\in Z(G)$ then clearly $f(b)f(a)=f(a)f(b)$ satisfy the homomorphism property.

But in general it doesn't, for example in $\mathbb{H}$: $f(ik)=(ik)^{-1}=k^{-1}i^{-1}=(-k)(-i)=ki\neq ik=f(i)f(k)$